# How to add all MySql tables for a given database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Hi all I am new to C# and MySQL and need help with the below.

```
string myConnection = "datasource=198.168.0.13;port=3306;username=xxxxx;password=xxxxxxxx";
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select * mydatabase.users ;", myConn);
```

**Users** is one of the tables.

I now need to add **table2** & **table3**. Can i put this on the same line as this:

```
myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select * mydatabase.users ;", myConn);
```

What is the syntax for this?